# Read csv file from Hadoop using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

I'm using spark-shell to read csv files from hdfs.
I can read those csv file using the following code in bash:

```
bin/hadoop fs -cat /input/housing.csv |tail -5
```

so this suggest the housing.csv is indeed in hdfs right now.
How can I read it using spark-shell?
Thanks in advance.

```scala
sc.textFile("hdfs://input/housing.csv").first()
```

I tried this way, but failed.

Comment: Firstly, really appreciate those answers. I used the following code and read successfully.`val df = sc.textFile("hdfs://master:9000/user/lab/README.md")`

Answer (score 1):

Include the csv package in the shell and

```
var df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("hdfs://x.x.x.x:8020/folder/file.csv")
```

8020 is the default port.

Thanks,
Ash

Comment: Hi Ash, I just checked the hadoop Web UI is `http://119.147.81.219:50070/dfshealth.html#tab-overview` So should I replace like `sc.textFile("hdfs://119.147.81.219:8020/housing.csv")`

Comment: You should confirm the location of the housing.csv, if it is in the root then the above should work, else you will have to mention the folder name as well. Try hadoop -fs ls commands

Answer (score 0):

You can read this easily with spark using `csv` method or by specifying `format("csv")`. In your case either you should not specify `hdfs://` or you should specify complete path `hdfs://localhost:8020/input/housing.csv`.

Here is a snippet of code that can read csv.

```
val df = spark.
        read.
        schema(dataSchema).
        csv(s"/input/housing.csv")
```